# How do you say "Smart device" in German? (not "smart phone")

Tags: translation

same as title:
How do you say "Smart device" in German? (not "smart phone")

Comment: A bit of context might help - what do you want to express? Smart Device is fairly unspecific concept.

Comment: Either use "smart devices" directly, or say "Smartphones/Telefone und Tablets". The concept of combining those device classes into one term isn't that common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Smart-Gerät* and *Smartgerät* both have some currency.  The optimal translation could depend on the context but for being understood this formulation is invincible.

The purer Anglicism *Smart Device* is also in use, but seems unnecessary.

Comment: I have never heard any of these words - in what context are they in use?

Comment: Among software engineers (perhaps with a bit of sarcasm) and on the internet.  (That goes for the German and the English - neither is very natural yet, but can be the most accurate term.)

Comment: I'm a native speaker, do consider myself an SE, and I used to do consulting in the field of smart grid SaaS, but I've never heard, seen or used *Smart-Gerät* by customers or any professional, not even marketing or C-level. Maybe a regionalism?

Comment: You can see it _has some currency_ in the wild: https://www.google.de/#q=%22smart-ger%C3%A4t%22&lr=lang_de&tbs=lr:lang_1de&start=10 (and https://www.google.de/#q=%22mit%20einem%20smart-ger%C3%A4t%22  https://www.google.de/#lr=lang_de&tbs=lr:lang_1de&q=%22das+smart-ger%C3%A4t%22 etc to catch less of the verb _geraten_).  _Smart-Device_ is out there too, personally I would not say it.

Answer (score 4):

Im Deutschen ist **Smart-Device** durchaus gängig. Je nach Kontext könnte man auch von **intelligenter Peripherie** sprechen, von **mitdenkenden Geräten** oder **intelligenter Sensorik**.

Comment: This is closest to reality. Never heard "mitdenkende Geräte", but a cursory survey of some IoT and smart grid providers' websites shows that the most common non-english term is **intelligentes Gerät**.